# What is trace-based seismic Inversion

Tags: geophysics, seismic, inversion

Looking through different literature articles and books concerning seismic inversion - mostly post-stack - phrases like "trace-based" and "model-based" keep appearing. I know that model-based in when lower-frequency info from either stacking velocities or low-pass sonic/rho logs are used. However, I do not know what trace-based inversion means or how it's performed. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have found this nomenclature rather confusing.  I am pretty sure that trace-based inversion is merely where each seismic trace is inverted independently of surrounding traces. This would take into account most deterministic/probabilistic inversion types (e.g. model, coloured, sparse, etc). In contrast, geostatistical inversion would not strictly be trace-based inversion, as it uses a spatial and temporal variogram to takes into account the expected results of surrounding traces during the inversion, even though it does invert on a trace-by-trace basis. Confusing.

The following paper describes trace and geostatistical inversion methods:
[Germán Merletti, and Julio Hlebszevitsch. 2003. Geostatistical Inversion for the Lateral Delineation of Thin Layer Hydrocarbon Reservoirs: A Case Study in San Jorge Basin, Argentina. SEG 2003.](http://www.cgg.com/data/1/rec_docs/3037_Geostatistical_Inversion_San_Jorge_SEG_2003.pdf)

I've found the following paper very useful for understanding seismic inversion (geostatistical isn't discussed, though): 
[Dennis Cooke and John Cant. 2010. Model-based Seismic Inversion: Comparing deterministic and probabilistic approaches. CSEG Recorder, Vol. 35, No. 4.](http://csegrecorder.com/articles/view/model-based-seismic-inversion-comparing-deterministic-and-probabilistic)

Comment: Just to add, trace-based inversions tend to assume that the data can be modeled as a convolutional process. This is a large simplification from the actual wave propagation, seismic acquisition, and data processing steps that need to occur before obtaining each post-stack trace.